# Corrigir HTML de uma página utilizando Ruby/Nokogiri

Tags: ruby

Eu estou com uma pequeno dificuldade em consumir um HTML gerado por uma página de terceiros, onde o HTML está com algumas tags de fechamento faltando.

Por exemplo:

```
<div>
  <li>
    <div>
      <div>test
        test
      </div>
      <li>
        <div>test 
          <div>test2</div>
        </div>
```

Executando o parse do Nokogiri

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(open('origem.html'))
```

O resultado é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou em HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
    <html><body><div>
      <li>
        <div>
          <div>test
            test
          </div>
          <li>
            <div>test 
              <div>test2</div>
            </div>
    </li>
    </div>
    </li>
    </div></body></html>
```

Sendo que o correto seria algo parecido com:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<div>
<li>
  <div>
    <div>test
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div>test 
    <div>test2</div>
  </div>
</li>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592389/how-to-correctly-fix-unclosed-html-tags-with-nokogiri) foi enviada no SO.

Basicamente utilizando a gem [Nokogumbo](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogumbo) em conjunto com a Nokogiri, onde o parse HTML5 resulta na mesma correção de HTML utilizada pelo Google Chrome!

Funciona lindamente!